# Force Outlook to prioritize a contact's primary email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible in Outlook, given how it has a lot of odd simple limitations, but I am trying anyways:

In an Outlook contact, you can enter **Email 1**, **Email 2**, and **Email 3** for a contact.

I have 2 questions:

1. Does Outlook make any distinguishment itself between these addresses? Does it internally "prioritize" Email 1 over, say, Email 3? Intuitively, it seems like **Email 1** should be a primary's contact email.
2. How can I force Outlook to "prioritize" a contact's **Email 1** address over **Email 2** and **Email 3**? Specifically, since the most common use of Contacts is auto-complete when sending an email, how can Outlook be set up so that if multiple email addresses are on file for a contact, the first auto-complete result will be **Email 1**, followed by **Email 2**, followed by **Email 3**, *regardless of alphabetical ordering of the email addresses*.

The way my Outlook is currently set up, auto-complete only pays attention to alphabetization. If a contact's primary email address is first alphabetically, it works out. If not, auto-complete gives you a contact's reserve, backup, or rarely used, etc. email address and instead of hitting ENTER, you manually have to correct it so it doesn't do this.

As a footnote, the Auto Complete list can't have entries removed without clearing the whole thing. A one-time email to a different address shouldn't cause this behavior permanently. The only workaround is to clear the the auto-complete list and then compose a dummy email and add all the "good" addresses while not selecting the "reserve" email addresses.

However, I would like to see *all* email addresses for a contact, just in the order they appear in the contact, rather than alphabetically.

How can this be done? If it can't be done, it basically necessitates not storing more than one email address per contact in Outlook, i.e. storing only basic contact info in Outlook and storing complete contact information in an Excel spreadsheet instead that has a "Email Priority" column, and that sounds like it might have been a good idea in 1985, but not today. Outlook is *supposed* to be a one-stop mail and contact solution...

Comment: Outlook AutoComplete is based on contact’s display name. You can change the Display name for each Email address.  Currently, there is indeed no option to "prioritize" a contact's Email 1 address over Email 2 and Email 3. Autocomplete will first find which one matches best and then list the one which you used most recent on the top.

Comment: Add this one: We can delete single autocomplete cache via clicking the ‘X’ in the right side of the address cache